# Loading Tensorflow models from disk is instant while loading from gcs is very slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, tensorflow-serving

I want to use Tensorflow serving to load multiple Models. If I mount a directory containing the model, loading everything is done in an instant, while loading them from a `gs://` path takes around 10 seconds per model.

While researching the issue I discovered this is probably a Tensorflow issue and not a Tensorflow Serving issue as loading them in Tensorflow is a huge difference as well:

```
[ins] In [22]: %timeit tf.saved_model.load('test/1')
3.88 s ± 719 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

[ins] In [23]: %timeit tf.saved_model.load('gs://path/to/test/1')
30.6 s ± 2.66 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Then it could be that downloading the model (which is very small) is slow, but I tested this as well:

```
def test_load():
    bucket_name = 'path'
    folder='test'
    delimiter='/'
    file = 'to/test/1'

    bucket=storage.Client().get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blobs=bucket.list_blobs(prefix=file, delimiter=delimiter) # Excluding folder inside bucket
    for blob in blobs:
        print(blob.name)
        destination_uri = '{}/{}'.format(folder, blob.name)
        blob.download_to_filename(destination_uri)

[ins] In [31]: %timeit test_load()
541 ms ± 54.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Any idea what is happening here?